# What effect has javascript obfuscation on speed on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, mobile, obfuscation

I want to ask if someone measured impact of some javascript obfuscators on the resulted code. I am aiming mobile users so the speed is cruicial. And I am especially trying to run 2 or 3 different obfuscators on same code in a row, which obfuscates the code very well, but I am afraid that it will have some speed impact.

Comment: Obfuscation generally focuses on removing information that is not required for the program, but is useful to the programmer. So if any effect will be present, the obfuscated program will only run *faster* than the original one. The smaller the code, the shorter the variable names and the less unnecessary stuff there is (ie, comments), the faster the execution. Unless your obfuscators are very agressive and *add* more stuff to the program to make analyser's life difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most JavaScript obfuscators only *minifies* and rename local variables, which is extremely easy to reverse-engineer with a beautifier.

The best combination I've found is the [DojoToolkit](http://www.dojotoolkit.org) and the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode.

Closure in Advanced Mode makes JavaScript code almost impossible to reverse-engineer, even after passing through a beautifier.  Once your JavaScript code is obfuscated beyond any recognition and any possibility to reverse-engineer, your HTML won't disclose much of your secrets.

This link for using the Dojo Toolkit with the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode for mobile applications:

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/file/n2636749/Using_the_Dojo_Toolkit_with_the_Closure_Compiler.pdf?by-user=t

The Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode actually makes JavaScript runs *faster* in mobile environments due to its industrial-scale optimizations.  For example, in-lining of functions, virtualization of prototype methods, namespace folding, dead-code removal etc. will all make code run faster, so it is not only an obfuscator, it is an optimizing compiler as well.

My own benchmarks runs code on the iPad around 10-20% faster, and 30% faster on the Android.  Memory usage is also reduced.

Answer (score 4):

it shouldn't.  Compiler/interpreters couldn't care less about what your *symbols* are, as long as they are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your question really needs an analysis on your own javascript in order to arrive at a useful answer.

Often though, obfuscation actually speeds up javascript since the file sizes are reduced (faster loading) and symbols get small names (less to compare against).

Answer (score 1):

If the obfuscator is doing some encoding and calling eval, like some do, then there will be a performance penalty at script load time. After that is run, there should be no difference and, as stated before, it may speedup your code due to slower size.

Comment: +1: If the obfuscator you are using is wrapping everything in `eval()` statements, the JS engine has to interpret both the obfuscator's code and the `eval()`ed code. However, for any **minificator** (simply shortens symbols and condenses statements), there will be no negative impact whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you mean by obfuscation.

If you're referring to minification, using a tool like JSMin, then the effect is nil.

If you're talking about something like Packer, the eval process actually does have an impact on how long it takes for the code to execute.  On a slow device, that impact can be significant.